# How to create a histogram for my dice function?

Tags: matlab, histogram, dice

I created a dice function but i don't know how to create a histogram for it. Each bin in the histogram should represent a possible value of for the sum of the dice. For example, for NumDice = 1, the bins should span the values 1 to 6. For NumDice = 2 the bins should range from 2 to 12. thanks!

```
function SumDice=RollDice(NumDice,NumRolls)
NumDice=1
NumRolls=500
distribution=zeros(NumDice*6,1);
for roll=1:NumRolls
  diceValues = randi(6,[NumDice 1]);
  totaldiceValue = sum(diceValues);
        distribution(totaldiceValue) = distribution(totaldiceValue) +1;
end
end
```

Comment: Is this some homework question going around at the moment? I just answered two questions on exactly this topic! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487403/how-to-plot-a-probability-density-function-on-a-histogram) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486093/summing-up-dice-in-matlab) for some suggestions on improving your code. ps, I'm downvoting your question as you clearly did NOT bother to check questions currently on SO before posting.

Comment: @ColinTBowers I noticed this too. Someone must have sent the entire class here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) function to plot a bar graph when you already have the values of each bar.

```
valueMin = NumDice;
valueMax = 6 * NumDice;

bar(valueMin:valueMax, distribution(valueMin:valueMax), "hist")
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot! Out of curiosity, why am I getting a graph that looks like http://i1308.photobucket.com/albums/s617/pingchu93/graph_zpsd389fa40.jpg instead of one that looks like http://i1308.photobucket.com/albums/s617/pingchu93/graph_zps0c8e0851.jpg

Comment: @Nicole, look at the documentation for changing the bar width (e.g. the link on `bar` above).  You can use `title`, `xlabel`, and `ylabel` to label the figure and the axes.  Hope that helps.